# How to force fsck at every boot - all (relevant) filesystems?

Tags: debian, fsck

I'm working with a fanless PC (hundreds of them, in fact) that has debian 6 and 3 partitions( FAT and 2x ext2). The system doesn't have a power button as such so most people tend to yank the plug to 'shut it down' rather than init 0 (or equivalent). As a result the filesystem(s) build up errors pretty rapidly.

I've tried using 'shutdown -rF' to force fsck but this doesn't seem to be working. I'm wondering if there is some way to tell the system to check each mount point / FS before they are mounted.

I've tried setting the fsck param in /etc/fstab. This typically gives me a 'Errors found. Run fsck manually' message.

Are there other options to try?

Comment: A) Who were your users? B) Could you have added a prominent "Shut Down" button which was always visible onscreen? C) Alternatively, could you have educated your users? D) Why did the machines not have power buttons on the front?

Comment: This question is a near-duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180488/force-e2fsck-on-var-at-every-boot by the same user.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In `/etc/init.d/checkfs.sh` is the line `if [ -f /forcefsck ] || grep -s -w -i "forcefsck" /proc/cmdline`, so providing `forcefsck` on the kernel command line or generating a `/forcefsck` file on shutdown should cause an fsck on the next reboot.

To prevent manual fsck runs, ask `fsck` to try to automatically fix errors with the `-y` option by uncommenting and changing no to `yes` in the following /etc/default/rcS entry, after the edit it should look like:

```
# automatically repair filesystems with inconsistencies during boot
FSCKFIX=yes
```

One option (forcefsck or FSCKFIX) does not imply the other.

Comment: Will this handle the 'Run fsck manually' condition?

Comment: Indeed, I read too fast, updated my answer.

Comment: I have set both FSCKFIX=yes and the value in `checkfs.sh`. In neither case did fsck run when I rebooted (via init 6). I must be missing something here.

Comment: Don't change anything in `checkfs.sh`, only edit /etc/defaults/rcS and run `touch /forcefsck` before reboot. The last command needs to be run before *every* restart or just after you booted but the fsck init script is done.

Comment: Hmm.. no luck. I still see the 'mounting unchecked filesystem' message followed by lots of 'delete inode referenced' errors. So far changing /etc/fstab has been the only thing has had any effect. Not sure what I'm doing such that your suggestions aren't working.

Comment: Interesting: I set the bit in fstab to 2 and rebooted. This time all the interactive fsck questions got a 'yes'. I wonder if it's a combination of the FSCKFIX=yes and the fstab entry that would work.

Comment: See `man 5 fstab`, the "second number" means `The sixth field: is used by the fsck(8) program to determine the order in which filesystem checks are done`, 0 means no fsck, 1 means first (usually for the root fs) and 2 means after that.

Answer (score 10):

Add the `fsck.mode=force` Kernel parameter on your bootloader. Append this option to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` variable inside `/etc/default/grub`. As root, generate a new grub configuration file:

`[root@host]# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

This parameter have the same effect as creating the `forcefsck` file inside the root of the mount point.

The solution of using the `checkfs.sh` script will better fit on Debian, but should not work on other distros

Comment: ~~Instead of changing every entry, there should be a GRUB entry for this like the Advanced/Recover mode entry. ~~ I take back what I say, hack, grub entries are useless in headless mode ...

Answer (score 8):

I am editing my answer:

The command is:

```
sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sdX
```

according to manpages -c argument for tune2fs counts number of instances of mounts for a partition. Hence, 1 forces to check the fs after every mounting instance.

(http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tune2fs.8.html)

Comment: Only a command is not enough in most cases, write at least a minimal explanation, too.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, since I have to fix my corrupted fylesystem (Ubuntu 16 LTS) very often. I put a new Kingston SSD one year ago, so I don't know exactly why this issue is so recurrent.

Comment: Does this also fixes any issues without user input? like with -y ?